# PowerShell: Enabled status blank for get-adgroupmember

Tags: powershell

The below script fetches all the Active Directory groups and their corresponding members, but my enabled status output is blank.

I want to get the enabled status in the output along with the other 3 properties.

I run my code as code.ps1 >> user.txt.

```
ForEach ($GroupName in (Get-ADGroup -Filter *))
 {
 "The AD Group $GroupName.Name members are:"
 Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName.Name | Select Name,samAccountName,Enabled,ObjectClass | Where {$_.ObjectClass -eq "user"} | Where {$_.Enabled -eq $true}
 "`n"
 }
```

Sample output:

```
Name                          samAccountName                Enabled                       ObjectClass                  
----                          --------------                -------                       -----------                  
Iliyas Ismail                 ilismail                                                    user                         
Ramesh Sengodan               rasengodan                                                  user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ForEach ($GroupName in (Get-ADGroup -Filter *))
{
     $GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName.Name | Where {$_.ObjectClass -eq "user"} | Get-ADUser -Properties Enabled | Where {$_.Enabled -eq $true} | Select Name,samAccountName,Enabled,ObjectClass 

     if ($GroupMembers) {
         "The AD Group $($GroupName.Name) members are:"
         $GroupMembers
         "`n"
     }
 }
```

- Your code was writing the name of all groups (whether they had users or not, although not quite correctly as you need to use a subexpression `$()` to access the property of an object in a `".."` string). My version modifies that to only write that line if the group actually has user members.
- It's generally a good idea to [filter left](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.09.windowspowershell.aspx), that is to say the `Where` should be used as far left as possible.
- The `Enabled` property of a user is not returned by default, so you need to pipe the results to `Get-ADUser` and then specify that you want that property returned via the `-Properties` parameter.

Comment: Sorry I have tried it, it is giving incorrect output half of the groups came out empty, but enabled status is show now, still this script is in usable.

Comment: Is that perhaps because some of the groups are returning non users, like computer accounts etc?

Comment: No sir!! My entire Remote Desktop Users group has not been fetched(it has only users) and many like this. To be frank I have tried this script already but it failed. I have posted in stack overflow only after trying everything in internet and trying by myself.

Comment: Modified my answer, try that.